# How to logout from IdentityServer4-client from External IdentityServer4 using FrontChannelLogout

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer4 ***identity-server-client*** as a client for an external IdentityServer4 ***identity-server-master*** I have some issues with logging out from ***identity-server-client*** when signing out at ***identity-server-master***. I have specified  *SignedOutCallBackPath* and *RemoteSignedOutPath* in **AddOpenIdConnect** for ***identity-server-master*** in ***identity-server-client***. I have also specified *FrontChannelLogoutUri* and *PostLogoutRedirectUri* for the client.

I have followed this sample from [Identity Server 4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/host/Startup.cs).

Configuration in the ***identity-server-client***

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("demoidsrv", "IdentityServer", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

                options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io/";
                options.ClientId = "implicit";
                options.ResponseType = "id_token";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-idsrv";
                options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-idsrv";
                options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout-idsrv";

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
            })
```

...And the configuration in ***identity-server-master*** from their [demo instance](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Config.cs)

```
                new Client
            {
                ClientId = "implicit",
                ClientName = "Implicit Client",
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                RedirectUris = { "https://notused" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://notused" },
                FrontChannelLogoutUri = "http://localhost:5000/signout-idsrv", // for testing identityserver on localhost

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "email", "api" },
            },
```

The problem is that when it tries to make a front channel sign out, it cannot find the path. I'm clueless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding an endpoint for front-channel-logout that basically kills the ongoing session. I do not know if this is the best solution as I understand that front-channel-logout can be used with an iframe on the logged-out page in IdentityServer4.